# How do I keep my footer at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble, my footer won't stay at the bottom of the page, it "sticks" to the bottom of the screen when I scroll.

It ends up covering up parts of the page as I scroll and gets quite annoying.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="footer" style="text-align: center">
    <p>Designed by ddrossi93. &copy;2015. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#footer {
border-top:1px solid;
text-align: center;
height: 60px;
background: #789;
font-weight: bold;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
}
```

If you need more info, let me know and I can post more of my code.

Comment: It sticks because of `position:fixed`. If you don't want it fixed to the bottom, remove that css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `position:fixed`to`position:relative`,not `position:absolute`. `fixed`makes your element stay at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and will not move when scrolled.If you change to `absolute`,you have to add `position:relative` to the containing block or the ancestor,so it will not sit in the middle of your page.Change to `relative` is the right way.

As to "some white space left at the bottom"? Try to add the following code in your style:
`body {margin:0;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
 position: fixed;
```

Means your footer will hover at the bottom of the page, the same way a navbar will on many websites. If you want your footer to stay at the bottom of the page, you need to change `position` to something else like `absolute` or `relative`. Here's a link to more info. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: awesome. It fixed it when I changed it to relative. Thanks a lot. Now there is some white space left at the bottom. I want the footer to cut that all out. How do I fix that?

Comment: Without seeing your page, I can only speculate that your 'height: 60px;' is too much. Try a smaller number or post a link to your page.

Comment: changing the height did not help. Here's my code if you wanna take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/t7aLgz9u/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position in the CSS to absolute.

```
#footer {
border-top:1px solid;
text-align: center;
height: 60px;
background: #789;
font-weight: bold;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed it to relative and it fixed my problem. When I changed it to absolute, it sat in the middle of my page

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set the margin and padding of the body element to 0;

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```